# Cannot save array to session, comes up empty

Tags: php, session, session-variables

If you can get this simple SESSION VARIABLES example to work, I'll hug you!
I can't get Session Variables to work at all on my site.  I'm running php5, on Windows 7, using Chrome browser.

Here's the send page:

```
    <?php
     session_start();
     $red='red';
     $blue='blue';
     $green='green';

     $SESSVARS=array($red,$blue,$green);

     $_SESSION['USERVARS']= $SESSVARS; 

     ?>

 <p>Set Sessionvars</p>
 <form action="SessVarCheck.php" method="post">
 <input name="Submit" type="submit">
 </form>
```

Here's the result page:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    echo "val 1:".$_SESSION['USERVARS'][0];
    echo "val 2:". $_SESSION['USERVARS'][1];
    echo "val 3:". $_SESSION['USERVARS'][2];
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SessVarCheck.php</title>
</head>

<body>
The Result page
</body>
</html>
```

I get empty on all three echos. 
Any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: What are you running on the server? (or is this all local)

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump($_SESSION);?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the call to `session_start()` happens before any page contents are output, on both pages. (See "Note" section [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php))

(I assume you may already know about this, but given that I don't see a "<html>" on the send page I thought there might be more to that script. Also, I don't know how sensitive this requirement is - just the spaces before the php tag might be enough to be a problem.)

Comment: AHA!I was running this locally on my IIS 7 testing server. When I upload it to my web host, which is Apache, running on Linux, it works fine. An oddity of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things:

1) do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` on your results page, to see what the raw contents of the session are

2) Verify that the sessions are working correctly. Add `echo "SessionID: " . session_id();` to both scripts, somewhere AFTER the session_start() calls. If you don't get the same session ID on each page, you're getting a new session each time and it's most likely a cookie problem.

Comment: I haven't closed this because session variables still don't work on my IIS testing server, even though theres no problem on my Linux/Apache web host.  I'll leave it open in case anybody stumbles across an answer